# Shape is not in the right position when pressing left and arrow key in java

Tags: java, android, swing, netbeans, awt

Im having this pacman game.Its already working however im having problem with he other shape specifically pacman's eyes. The problem is that when i press left and up arrow key the position of the eyes get the wrong position. See attach picture

Can someone help me on this. Here is my code.

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
    {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        //pacman
        graphics.setColor(Color.yellow);
        graphics.fillArc(xLocation, yLocation, 100, 100, angle, mouth);

        //eyes
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fillOval(xLocationEyes, yLocationEyes, 20, 20);
        food(graphics);
    }
 @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyboard) {


int keyboardPress = keyboard.getKeyCode();
         if(keyboardPress == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
             if(xLocation + 130 >= getWidth()){
                 xLocationEyes = getWidth()-130;
                 xLocation = 600-160;
             }

             xLocation += 30;
             xLocationEyes += 30;
             angle = 45;
             repaint();
     }
 if(keyboardPress == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

         if(xLocation  <= 0){
             xLocationEyes = 45;
             xLocation = 30;

         }
         angle = -145;
         xLocation -= 30;            
         xLocationEyes -= 30;
         repaint();

     }
}
```

Comment: Just change the position of the eye based on the direction

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried that but the two shapes (pacman and his eyes) are not syncing.

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you please give some sample here. Appreciate it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: If by 'this' you mean 'help for solving the problem' then you missed it. If you mean a solution to the actual problem, then I'll look at it more closely when you post the MCVE. For the moment, -1 ignoring the advice already offered while going on to ask a question that implies none was offered.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes sir this means the problem I stated above specifically the question sir. Can you please offer solution for this.

Comment: @AndrewThompson what's with the attitude mate? My question is, basing from my question above and the exmaples, how can I fix the position of the pacman's eyes when pressing the left arrow key because the location of the eyes are not position well. When pressing the right arrow key the eyes are position well.

Answer (score 1):

Pac-Man, one of my favorite arcade games, face is not symetrical. When you flip the body over a horizontal axis you also need to flip his eye. This is mostly just some tinkering with numbers on your part, but when you call the following line of code

```
if(keyboardPress == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

      //i dont know what this does so tread at your own will
     if(xLocation  <= 0){
         xLocationEyes = 45;
         xLocation = 30;

     }

     angle = -145;
     xLocation -= 30;   
     //tinker with this value and the value of you moving the eye back when moving right         
     xLocationEyes += 30; //note the += this may fix your issue
     repaint();

 }
```

Comment: just tinker with the eye x value and you will get it eventually

Comment: Iyeah it work for the first press. But since its + it will move to the right so the eye is moving to the right..

Comment: Any other solution here